# Why don't Raptor engines use CH3Cl instead of CH4?

Tags: spacex, mars, fuel

The boiling point of CH<sub>3</sub>Cl is -24 degrees Celsius, whereas the boiling point of CH<sub>4</sub> is -160 degrees Celsius.

The density of CH<sub>3</sub>Cl is 2.3 g/cm<sup>3</sup>, whereas the density of CH<sub>4</sub> is 0.6 g/cm<sup>3</sup>.

CH<sub>3</sub>Cl is polar, hence reactive as well. Also, perchlorate salts found on Mars, which could be used to synthesize Cl<sub>2</sub> to monochlorinate CH<sub>4</sub> (produced from the [Sabatier reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabatier_reaction): CO<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O → CH<sub>4</sub> + O<sub>2</sub>) in the presence of sunlight (free radical halogenation reaction of CH<sub>4</sub>).

Comment: Possibly because the Environmental Impact Assessment for a chlorine-gas-spewing death machine will be a bit more difficult to pass? Possibly because the fuel weight 3.15 times as much per molecule, yet releases only 85.8% as much energy, thus in total it is only 27% as good a fuel?

Comment: I would also assume price could be a good reason.

Comment: @BojanKogoj I think PcMan's covers it well. Even if CH3Cl was a tiny fraction of a percent of the cost of methane (which is not the case), a "chlorine-gas-spewing death machine" would still be a very bad idea.

Comment: The engine should not be destroyed by the reaction of chlorine with the metals of the engine-

Comment: @DavidHammen yet hydrazine and other hypergolics are commonly used. These are extremely poisonous (to the point a tiny droplet can kill you, hence crews needing to use full NBC suits when handling the stuff). Can remember the problems when the F-16 was first introduced which had a small amount of hydrazine for an emergency pump or something...

Comment: @jwenting hydrazine and other hypergolics produce exhaust with a mixture of CO2, H2O, and N2, not ~1/3 hydrochloric acid.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff true, but doesn't take away that having those fuels is a seriously dangerous proposition. Not as much a problem at Canaveral where launches are over the sea, but for places where spent stages drop on land it's a problem. That includes most launch sites, including those in China and Russia, as well as SpaceX's Texas location and (for non-polar launches) Vandenberg (which is one reason no eastward launches are performed from there).

Comment: @jwenting first, that they're bad doesn't change the fact that hydrochloric acid exhaust would be even worse. Second, SpaceX doesn't use those propellants in either Falcon 9 or Starship. Third, SpaceX plans to only operate fully reusable launch vehicles from their Texas site, so there won't *be* any "spent stages", let alone hypergolic ones. Fourth, they wouldn't be dropping stages on land from any of those sites even if they were using expendable launchers.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I'm not so sure about that. I mean, you'd *think* the hydrogen chloride in the exhaust would be a major issue, but then you look at [what solid rocket fuel is commonly made of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_perchlorate_composite_propellant) and what its combustion products are. I'm pretty sure the real reasons are simply cost and performance.

Comment: You seem concerned about the boiling point of the fuel. Propane has a boiling point comparable to CH3Cl and is a much better fuel. Both propane and CH3Cl are more difficult to make on Mars than CH4 (which is formed by default when you react CO2 with an excess of H2, giving 3 substances that are easily separable due to very different boiling points: H2O, CH4 and unreacted H2.) But I don't understand the concern. 1 ton of CH4 needs 4 tons of O2 (of similar boiling point) for combustion so the problem of preventing O2 boiloff exists anyway. It's quite convenient that CH4 and O2 have similar b.p.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen even decomposing pure ammonium perchlorate wouldn't produce as much HCl in the exhaust, and real solid propellants contain fuels and additives as well. And it is considered a problem for their use.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

They chose $\rm CH_4 + O_2$ because that is a much, much better fuel.

$\rm CH_3Cl$ does burn with $\rm O_2$, producing:
$$\rm 2CH_3Cl + 3O_2 \to 2CO_2 + 2H_2O + 2HCl + {\sim}1528\text{ kJ/mol energy}$$
This from a total atomic mass of $2(50.5) + 3(32) = 197\text{ g/mol}$.
Your fuel, combusted with oxygen, thus delivers some $7.8\text{ kJ/g}$.

However, this combustion liberates hydrogen chloride gas. On reacting with water, say the moisture on your lungs or eyeballs, this promptly turns into hydrochloric acid. This tends to be bad for your health, and the EPA tends to frown on the release of multiple tons of hydrogen chloride gas in a sensitive environment (like anywhere on the surface of the Earth), so getting clearance on your Environmental Impact Assessment might be difficult.

Meanwhile, methane and oxygen burn with $$\rm CH_4 + 2O_2 \to CO_2 + 2H_2O + 890.8\text{ kJ/mol}.$$
This from a total atomic mass of $16 + 2(32) = 80\text{ g/mol}$.
Methane, combusted with oxygen, thus delivers some $11.1\text{ kJ/g}$.
This combustion generates $\rm CO_2$, water and heat. Much more benign to the environment.

Note: above combustion equations assume perfect combustion, not optimised for use in rockets, no consideration of incomplete combustion, etc. It's simply a mass vs energy checkup, with consideration of the waste products generated.

Comment: NASA did manage to get clearance for the [shuttle SRBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster), which each held 500 tons of [APCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_perchlorate_composite_propellant) fuel containing (if I did my math right) about 20% chlorine by mass. So apparently spewing about 200 tons of hydrogen chloride into the atmosphere per launch is OK, at least as long as you're a government agency and don't do it too often.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Quite true. And the particulate Aluminium oxides from the SRBs caused problems of their own. NASA got a lot of flak for this, but at that time they were *king*, and mostly immune to critique. Still are, frankly. But a private company like SpaceX? Heh! Still, if the fuel was actually better, not 3 times worse than Methane, it might have been used. But it isn't, so it won't.

Comment: Chloride is also pretty darn corrosive to most metals, seems like that might also play a role in something you want to keep around for a while

Comment: Given the environmental considerations against $\rm CH_3Cl$ I wonder why $\rm ClF_3$ was even considered as a rocket propellant oxidizer...

Comment: @Ruslan: AIUI, from reading the same book I'm sure you're referring to, $\rm ClF_3$ was mainly considered for 1) military use, where strategic concerns tend to override environmental ones, and 2) as a deep-space propellant, where environmental concerns are negligible (assuming your rocket doesn't explode on its way to space).

Comment: @Ruslan to add to what IlmariKaronen said, recall that the EPA was only formed in late 1970, and they were looking into that hellish liquid in the 1940’s through the 60’s, at least

Comment: This particular engine is intended to be capable of missions that require refuelling on the surface of Mars. The plan is to manufacture methane from water and CO2 found on Mars. Would manufacturing CH3Cl on Mars be more difficult, easier, or about the same?

Comment: @Robyn Compared to making Methane; much more effort. The pathway you show requires CH4 be made *as an intermediary step* the make the CH3Cl. Yes it is easier to store, but you also need to make O2 and store that already, so you gain nothing.

Comment: There is either a minus to much or a minus missing in these formulas.

Comment: @Arsenal yep. blame the persons(multiple) that edited the heck out of the answer after I posted it. I think they read tilde (~) meaning approximate, as negative. But when i try to edit the math text, it goes crazy on me.

Comment: Ah yes, \approx should fix that in MathJax I think.

Comment: @Ruslan ClF3 was considered for the same reason and by the same people that also played with FOOF (Dioxygen Diflouride), one of the very few things that burns explosively with Asbestos!. Insanity may or may not have been a factor.

Comment: Is there any chance of condensation of HCl + H2O on the hull on descent? Which would be capital BAD? I mean, there *is* condensed soot, and the tanks are potentially cold.

Comment: @Arsenal: Hmm, weird. There was a tilde ($\text{~}$) in the formula until PcMan edited it after your comments, and no minus signs AFAICT. Are you sure you didn't misread it as a minus sign yourself? Maybe ${\sim}$ would look better?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen the MathJax \text{~} renders like a minus on my screen I've just checked again. I cannot distinguish it from a -. Only when I select it, there is a slight blur, which indicates a more complex form, and when I copy it, I get indeed a ~. But yes \sim is what I meant and is very distinct.

Comment: @Arsenal: Weird. [It's very obviously a tilde on my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTiLs.png) Maybe a font difference? (I'm on Firefox / Mac.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen In your comment it renders fine, in the text body it does not. I'm on a 1680x1050 screen under Chrome / Windows. Maybe I need to adjust some ClearType Setting or something. Fonts are horrible under Windows...

Answer (score 7):

### "Why do we use ______ rocket fuel?" is complicated.

I recently read John Clark's *Ignition!: An informal history of liquid rocket propellants*, which I highly recommend. It's exactly what the title implies, and covers the history of fuel development, touching lightly on the pre-WW2 era, then hitting every major development through the sixties (i.e. it covers the time when most of the major development was done).

Before describing further, I'll mention that Elon Musk apparently puts a lot of stock in this book in particular. So, whatever *Ignition!* says is likely to have had a large influence on the fuels SpaceX uses. However, this influence is likely somewhat perverse: Clark spends about 180 pages gleefully recounting all the amusing ways people blew themselves up, or poisoned themselves, etc. with rocket fuels, while hunting for hypergolicity, temperature range, and an oxidizer that wouldn't spontaneously turn into green slime.

Instead, SpaceX seems to have read ignition as a cautionary tale, and went with liquid methane and LOX. This is most notable for being one of Tsiolkov's original suggested rocket fuels, way back at the dawn of rocketry. Liquid gas handling isn't exactly trivial, but it's way, way easier than most of the other options. In fact, Clark makes this exact point in his chapter on LOX and FLOX<sup>*</sup>, though he immediately traces the evolution of the most dangerous version of it (slushy liquid hydrogen and freon-ated liquid ozone!).

Overall, I suspect the folks at SpaceX wanted *very much* to avoid the excitement of modern rocket fuels, and methane was cheap, easy to work with, and had a minimum of exciting environmental impacts. Kerosene is the more usual default, but once you're handling cryonics anyway, you may as well go with a liquid-gas fuel.

---

<sup>*</sup> Clark says very little on Methane-LOX systems, but does mention someone's bright idea to make them into a monopropellant: "His idea was to set up a liquid oxygen plant alongside a natural gas well, tank up your ICBM on the spot, and push the button." Clark's horror at the idea of using a LOX-fuel *mix* as anything other than a bomb comes through clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Mere Speculation: The kinetics of that fuel's combustion may be too slow for a rocket motor. Halogens are known for their use as [flame retardants.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_retardant#Gas_phase_radical_quenching)